# Escaping normal text in date() doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, date

I can't work out why a date won't format how I want, I'm using:

```
date("F jS Y \a\t g:i a")
```

expecting to get:

```
August 11th 2015 _at_ 9:59 am
```

But instead I get:

```
August 11th 2015 _a_ 9:59 am
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\t` is an [escape sequence](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) and you have to escape it twice, otherwise PHP thinks it is a tab.

Like this:

```
date("F jS Y \a\\t g:i a")
             //^^ See here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
echo date("F jS Y \a\\t g:i a");
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.